# How to fix a hole in the mesh

Tags: modeling

I am watching Blender Guru's tutorial on how to make a donut and he is making a cup of coffee but for whatever reason whenever he does CTRL R to fix the hole in the middle of the liquid it works for him but I have tried it many times and it doesn't do anything. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I don’t think there is a hole - it looks to be refraction showing the inside of the cup. Try reducing the IOR of your shader and see if the problem goes away - that will show whether there actually is a hole. Also, check your normals as that is critical with refractive surfaces since flipped normals will also flip the refraction properties. Also check that you have a realistic IOR for the material being modelled (eg, typically in the range 1.0 for air to around 1.33).

Comment: There's definitely no hole, I agree with you. And I'm just watching the tutorial right now, of course Andrew is not using Ctrl+R to close a hole, he creates a loop cut to make the top edge sharper...

Comment: I’ve not seen the tutorial and couldn’t remember what Ctrl R did but  thanks for the reminder and clarification :-)

Answer (score 3):

how to get rid of holes:

[image]

**1: fill:** Select hole and press F to fill - OR press ctrl+F and select fill OR go to face > fill
[image]
[image]

**2: Grid fill:**
Select hole and press ctrl+F and select grid fill OR go to face > grid fill
[image]

**3: merge:**
Select hole and press M and merge at center OR mesh > merge > at center:
[image]

Comment: +1, though I think Rich Sedman is right and there's no hole in topology.